# SQL Joining two tables against multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way to join two tables against multiple columns for example in the first table we have:-

```
Headers = Name, AB1, AB2, AB3, AB4
Data = Lee, A, B, C ,D
```

Second table we have:-

```
Headers = Type, Time
Data = A,1
Data = B,2
Data = C,3
Data = D,4
```

I'm looking to join both tables so I get the following so each of the AB columns would look up the Time Value from the other table.

```
Name, AB1, AB2, AB3, AB4, AB1_time, AB2_time, AB3_time, AB4_time,
Lee, A, B, C, D, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

I was looking to do multiple joins but don't really know how to best go about it. The data above is an simple example but in reality I have Two massive SQL Tables that I will then clash with other data sets.

Comment: Could you expand your question to include more data?  An answer given for this trivial example might not be robust to a larger data set.

Comment: I've updated the above & yes you are correct the example above are to simplify the question. However in reality these data tables are massive.

Comment: Most probably simple  4 JOINs  will have the best perfomance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use multiple joins like this:

```
select t1.*, t2a.time. t2b.time, t2c.time, t2d.time
from t1 left join
     t2 t2a
     on t1.ab1 = t2a.type left join
     t2 t2b
     on t1.ab2 = t2b.type left join
     t2 t2c
     on t1.ab3 = t2c.type left join
     t2 t2d
     on t1.ab4 = t2d.type ;
```